# Clicking inside TinyMCE editor is firing onChange event

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using `TinyMCE 4.1.6`. I need to check for content changes. I tried using the `onChange` event (also tried with isDirty, keyup event).

OnChange is useful for capturing all the changes including formatting. But when the editor is clicked inside, the event fires and shows content changed, though nothing changed.

As an alternative, I have also tried storing old content and comparing with changed content using Jquery's `data()` function. But what happens is that when the editor is clicked inside, it adds *data-mce-selected="1"* as below:

```
<table data-mce-selected="1" class="mce-item-table" border="0"..>
```

So when this is compared with the old content it shows that the content changed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
e.preverntDefault()
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

just after the event handler function starts, I think it will stop mce from adding data-mce-selected="1" and your approach of comparing old data would work.

Comment: It did not help. I even tried adding these to onClick event.